# Managing a full screen view with support for popup dialogs (Cocoa/OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, fullscreen

I am working on a Cocoa app that consists of 5 views of varying shapes and sizes, some of these views are NSOpenGLViews.  I need to have functionality for any of these views to be able to take over the whole window and go into some sort of full screen mode.  I originally tried doing this with the method enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: but I ran into trouble when I would try and bring up a dialog window (this would result in a crash).  So it seems that I need to scale back my approach a little because I cannot live without these popup dialogs.

My new strategy is to stretch the view that is going into full screen mode so that it takes over the whole view of the screen and then enter into kiosk mode.  I was wondering if anyone had tried this type of approach to make a full screen view and if they could offer any advice about best practices for this type of implementation.

My main concern is that I need to preserve the state of the window when I leave full screen mode so I am wondering what would be the best way to hide the other views.  Could I just make the other views invisible and then stretch my full screen view to take over the window or would it be better to put the full screen view into a new window and then stretch this new window?  My first inclination is that it would be best to keep the full screen view in its original window because it seems this would interfere with event handling less.

Comment: Why don't you just try to fix the crash? You seem to be assuming that it can't be fixed. Can you post the crash log that appears when you try to display your dialog?

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but from what I understand, when you use enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: the view goes into full screen mode (as opposed to just becoming large and entering kiosk mode) and you cannot have any windows overlay it.  So even if I could prevent/fix this crash I couldn't have dialog windows popup.  Am I incorrect?